# which of these two methods is better for SAML architecture

Tags: saml

**Method 1** 
Browser is directed to Service provider. Service provider checks whether there is any cookie set, If no then it redirects browser to Identity provider and Identity provider(IdP) validates user and redirect a ID to Service Provider(SP). SP takes that ID and set it as session cookie in browser and redirects user to service. Next time, if user asks for service again in same session the SP checks for cookie and redirects directly to service.
**Method 2**
Browser is directed to Service provider. Service provider redirects to IdP. IdP checks for its cookie and if cookie is not present,IdP authenticates user and set session cookie in browser. Redirects positive response to SP. SP redirects user to service. Next time user asks for the service within the session, Browser is directed to Service provider. Service provider redirects to IdP.IdP checks for its cookie and if it is present,it sends positive response to SP.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that [Guanxi](http://codebrane.com/brane/node/7) implementation of Shibboleth (SAML2 profile) and almost sure that [Shibboleth itself](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/Home) can be simplified to your "method 1".

You better check some of existing SAML2 profile implementations.

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe either of those are valid SAML implementations. Usually in SAML identity information is communicated in a HTTP POST or through SOAP web service (see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Assertion_Markup_Language#SAML_2.0_bindings). Cookies are not used to 'authenticate' a user.

We have a web application that uses SAML 2.0 XML communicated in a HTTP POST to authenticate the user. Our customer's employees go through the identity provider on their side of the firewall to access our application.

Comment: :If cookies are not used then What is used to authenticate user? HTTP is a stateless protocol right? Who will keep track of user authenticated token?

Comment: Your app can use cookies to remember an authenticated user but it's not how SAML works. The identity provider (the other server who really knows who the user is) sends SAML XML either in a POST or through SOAP. Once your app (the source provider) has that it can maintain the user's session with a cookie.